# Pyspark remove strings (or imputate them) from numeric columns

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have some strings in a numeric columns. Like 1, 2, 3, 4, 'lol', 6 ...
I just wanna del this rows. How can I del them?

`.cast` did not return NaN. I wrote function, but it takes too much time (unreal), and it didn't work anyway...

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

def is_digit(val):
    try:
        is_num = str(val).replace(".", "", 1).isdigit() if val else False
        return is_num
    except:
        return False
    
is_digit_udf = F.udf(is_digit, BooleanType())
```

It's so stupid :(((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **`.rlike()`** function to **filter** only the rows that are not having numbers by specifying regex.

**`Example:`**

```
df.show()
+----+
| val|
+----+
|   1|
|   2|
|   3|
| lol|
|   6|
+----+

df.filter(col("val").rlike("[^a-zA-Z]")).show()

#or using [^\d] regex
df.filter(~col("val").rlike("[^\d]")).show()
#+---+
#|val|
#+---+
#|  1|
#|  2|
#|  3|
#|  6|
#+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you want to delete the rows which contain not a numeric value, right? Then simply cast and filter out the values.

```
df.printSchema()
df.show(10, False)

root
 |-- num: string (nullable = true)

+---+
|num|
+---+
|1  |
|2  |
|3  |
|lol|
|5  |
+---+


import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df.withColumn("num", f.col("num").cast("int")) \
  .filter(f.col("num").isNotNull()) \
  .show(10, False)

+---+
|num|
+---+
|1  |
|2  |
|3  |
|5  |
+---+
```